# Pass and escape JavaScript array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 arrays. First called order and storing 3 values between 1 - 6. Looks like this: `order[1,3,6]`. The other is multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
costMed = [['**1,100**','5,500'],['5,500','11,000'],['10,450','20,900']...];
```

I can access values from costMed by `costMed[0][1]` but need to access values by using result of order[n] like this:

`costMed(order[n][0])` so the result will be for instance **1,100** but can't figure out how to escape **order[n]**.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why would you need to escape it, just remember that arrays are zero based ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking about. However could it be that you want `costMed[order[n]][0]`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to escape anything but to correct the syntax:

```
array[level1 index][level2 index][level3 index]
```

as the level 1 index is in `order[n]` it's like this:

```
costMed [ order[n] ] [0]
```

(spaces just for readability)

or:

```
var l1 = order[n];
var l2 = 0;
costMed [ l1 ] [ l2 ]
```